# How can I write a regular expression so that the entire regex is a set containing two possible groups?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find instances of Roman Numerals followed by a stop and a space, like `IV.`, in a text. These indicate beginnings of verses. Some verses don't begin with Roman Numerals, however, so I've inserted `[NV]` tags at the beginning of these verses. I have a regex that can find the numerals and a regex that can find the `[NV]` tags, but I can't combine them in one regex that will look for one or other of these.

My regex for finding the numerals is:

```
numeralpat = re.compile(r'[IVX]{1,4}\. ')
```

I thought I could put this into a set with the other regex to find either a numeral or a `[NV]` tag:

```
numeralpat = re.compile(r'[(\[NV\])([IVX]{1,4}\. )]')
```

This causes a problem between brackets of the same type, so I've tried escaping different characters to make it work. None of this has worked for me. Can this be done using regex?

Edit to add sample text:

Text:

```
I. this is some text with a verse numeral
II. this is some text with a verse numeral
III. this is some text with a verse numeral
[NV]this is text with no verse numeral
IV. this is some text with a verse numeral
V. this is some text with a verse numeral
```

Expected matches:

```
'I. '
'II. '
'III. '
'[NV]'
'IV. '
'V. '
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify alternate lookups like so:  `r'(abc|def)'` - which looks for either `'abc'` or `'def'` - you should also escape the brackets to look for explicit `\[NV\]` not either `'N'` or `'V'` :

```
import re

regex = r"(\[NV\]|[IVX]{1,4}\.)"

test_str = ("I. Some text\n"
    "some Text\n"
    "II. some text\n"
    "[NV] more text\n")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum= matchNum,
           start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum= groupNum,
               start = match.start(groupNum),
               end = match.end(groupNum), 
               group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

Output:

```
Match 1 was found at 0-2: I.
Group 1 found at 0-2: I.
Match 2 was found at 23-26: II.
Group 1 found at 23-26: II.
Match 3 was found at 37-41: [NV]
Group 1 found at 37-41: [NV]
```

See https://regex101.com/r/MpMxcP/1

It looks for either `'[NV]'` or any of `'[IVX]'` up to 4 times followed by literal `'.'`

Answer (score 3):

You can combine both of your regexes using alternation like this,

```
(?:\[NV\]|[IVX]{1,4}\. )
```

This will either match `[NV]` OR any of `I` `V` `X` characters 1 to 4 times followed by a `.` and a space.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zk75Gi/2)**